# how to solve Error: Cannot find module 'kue'

Tags: node.js, kue

I am getting started on kue job queue an i am trying out if my producer works

producer.js

```
var kue = require('kue')
, redis = require('redis');

  kue.redis.createClient = function() {
    var client = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1');
    client.auth('');
    return client;
  };
  var jobs = kue.createQueue();

var sequence = 0;

setInterval(
  function() {
  sequence += 1;
  (function(sequence) {
  var job = jobs.create('email',{
  title: 'Hello #' + sequence
  ,to: 'whatemail@gmail.com'
  ,body: 'Hello from node!'
  }).save();

  job.on('complete', function(){
  console.log('job ' + sequence + ' completed!')
  });

  job.on('failed', function() {
  console.log('job ' + sequence + 'failed!')
  });
  })(sequence);
  }
  ,1000);
```

I however get the error Error: Cannot find module 'kue'.I however have installed kue globally.

This is the error

```
C:\kueapps>node producer.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'kue'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\kueapps\producer.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: Try installing it locally. On Unix, an alternative would be to set the  `NODE_PATH` variable so it includes the global `node_modules` directory, but I don't know if that'll work on Windows.

Comment: Thanks.I have installed it locally and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run

```
npm install kue
```

You could also ad the `--save` switch to the command, to save the dependency in your `package.config` file